# Почему не работает mapGetters?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Есть такой код -  копипаст из документации, но лишь с небольшой заменой на нужный существующий геттер:

```
computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
        posts: 'blog/posts'
    })
}
```

И в ответ браузер шлет мне ошибку:

```
Error: Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (51:4)

[0m [90m 49 | [39m
 [90m 50 | [39m  computed[33m:[39m {
[31m[1m>[22m[39m[90m 51 | [39m    [33m...[39mmapGetters([
 [90m    | [39m    [31m[1m^[22m[39m
 [90m 52 | [39m      [32m'posts'[39m
 [90m 53 | [39m    ])
 [90m 54 | [39m  }[33m,[39m[0m
```

На 51-ой строке находится это:

```
...mapGetters([
```

А вот этот код работает нормально:

```
computed: mapGetters({
    posts: 'blog/posts'
})
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить?

Comment: Ты же используешь опрератор разворота '...' он обычно служит для работы с массивами или в функциях для передачи массива в качестве нескольких аргументов https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Comment: @John-n ну я понимаю что делает троеточие. Вопрос в другом - почему не работает? Это код из документации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение проблемы:

```
yarn add babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread
```

И в файл `.babelrc` доавить эту строку:

```
{
    "plugins": [
        "transform-object-rest-spread",
        // ...
    ]
}
```

После этих телодвижений у меня все заработало.

Answer (score 0):

импорт делал?

```
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
  // ...
  computed: {
    // mix the getters into computed with object spread operator
    ...mapGetters([
      'doneTodosCount',
      'anotherGetter',
      // ...
    ])
  }
}
```

ключевое тут
`import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'`

Comment: Вы еще раз прочитайте, пожалуйста, что я написал... Мало того что в самом вопросе это есть, так я еще и ответ создал. Будьте внимательнее в следующий раз.